# Existence of a function from $[0,1]$ to an arbitrary measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

For any measurable $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ with measure 1, does there exist a continuous function 
$$T:[0,1]\to E$$
Such that $\mu\circ T=\mu$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on the real line?

Comment: Please do not edit old questions to ask a new question.  Instead, [ask a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: nvm it wasn't that hard to retype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A continuous image of $[0,1]$ is compact and connected.

Comment: I edited the question - sorry about that!